# Dialogflow detectIntent and return multiple intent names and confidence values

Tags: dialogflow-es

Using the standard version of Dialogflow

Sending a request to Dialogflow V2 API from the examples below.

When using other NLP services they will return a verbose response of multiple intents and their confidence scores

```
def detect_intent_texts(project_id, session_id, texts, language_code):
    """Returns the result of detect intent with texts as inputs. Using the same `session_id` between requests allows continuation
    of the conversation."""

    import dialogflow_v2 as dialogflow
    session_client = dialogflow.SessionsClient()

    session = session_client.session_path(project_id, session_id)
    print('Session path: {}\n'.format(session))

    for text in texts:
        text_input = dialogflow.types.TextInput(
            text=text, language_code=language_code)

        query_input = dialogflow.types.QueryInput(text=text_input)

        response = session_client.detect_intent(
            session=session, query_input=query_input)

        print('=' * 20)
        print('Query text: {}'.format(response.query_result.query_text))
        print('Detected intent: {} (confidence: {})\n'.format(
            response.query_result.intent.display_name,
            response.query_result.intent_detection_confidence))
        print('Fulfillment text: {}\n'.format(
            response.query_result.fulfillment_text))
```

Was expecting multiple intents to be returned but Dialogflow only returns top scoring intent

```
{
  "responseId": "",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "This i my utterance!",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/project/agent/intents/22",
      "displayName": "Intent1"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 0.8798916,
    "languageCode": "en"
  },
  "alternativeQueryResults": [
    {
      "queryText": "This is my utterance!",
      "languageCode": "en"
    }
  ]
}
```

LUIS response

```
{
  "query": "This i my utterance!",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "Intent1",
    "score": 0.532636642
  },
  "intents": [
    {
      "intent": "Intent1",
      "score": 0.532636642
    },
    {
      "intent": "Intent2",
      "score": 0.09986155
    },
    {
      "intent": "Intent3",
      "score": 0.0533027425
    }

  ]

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dialogflow will not return multiple intents**. It only returns the intent with maximum confidence score.